# Accessing Gmail emails through google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, gmail, google-api

How to get the e-mail contents by getting the user's login details in google app engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking a look at the GMail API. You'll probably want to use OAuth.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what I'm doing in my current project. Google App Engine Blog introduced a company named "Context.IO" and they provide very easy API to access GMail. I've implemented it in my project successfully.

**Links**
[GAE Blog](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2011/05/accessing-gmail-accounts-from-app.html)
[Demo](http://contextio-demo.appspot.com) (You can look for a contact, and get all its emails...)

**My Experience**
They also provide a Explore feature that allow you to post and get json data from your gmail accounts.
However, if you registered for a free API key here, they will limit to 3 mailboxes per day. You can run a cron job to delete it daily. The nice thing is that you can contact them to get more mailboxes for development purposes :)

Hope my experience can help you

Comment: Thanks for yor reply. Be frank, I'm new to GAE, could you help me to get API key

Comment: If youre talking about contextio api key, please follow their instructions on the homepage:-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use google service account. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount
Then you can use it in order to get access to account under your domain.

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('My App');
$client->setAuthConfigFile('path/to/service_account.json');

$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
// account that we want to check 
$client->setSubject('account@mydomain.com');
$client->setAccessType('offline');  
$client->setScopes([Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_READONLY]);

$service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
$messagesResponse = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me');
```